# Hot Towel SPA - trigger browser to save login details on form submit

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, hottowel

Just wondering if anyone knows of a trick to getting a Single Page App using Hot Towel (knockout, durandal & breeze) to trigger the event (assuming it's submit) that browser's hook into to prompt to save a username and password on a login form. I believe the submit event is suppressed (for obvious reasons) as it's not required in a SPA.

The only solution I can come up with at this point is to create a plain old HTML login page that triggers the loading of my SPA on login. And I guess the if there's a "pro" to this approach it's that the loading of the SPA happens during login which probably feels better in the sense of user flow because they feel like "important things are happening" during the login process...

Any idea/tips greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you go with the plain old HTML login page as this is the easiest way to get up and running quickly.

Authentication from within the SPA would require customization of each ajax API request to include a user authentication token of some sort.

Comment: I already have the authorization well and truly up and running and it's being handled by the most part by the GuardeRoute method - along with the fact that the Breeze Controller is decorated with Authorize attributes where necessary. I proposed the HTML solution in my original question as I agree with you that this seems to be a simple way to trigger the browser remember password feature - however I had no problems authenticating in Durandal just using plain old Ajax then redirecting the route - it's not that hard.